# while using id and xpath i am getting error but while using name i am not getting error

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

```
public class First {
public static String browser = "chrome";
public static WebDriver driver;
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    if (browser.equals("firefox")) {
        WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }

    if (browser.equals("chrome")) {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    driver.get("https://www.salesforce.com/in/");

    driver.findElement(
            By.xpath("//*[@id=\"main\"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/a")).click();

    Set<String> windowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();

    Iterator<String> windowIterator = windowHandles.iterator();
    String parentWindow = windowIterator.next();
    String childWindow = windowIterator.next();

    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

    driver.switchTo().window(childWindow);

    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

    driver.findElement(By.id("UserFirstName-m8NQ")).sendKeys("sam");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='UserFirstName-m8NQ']")).sendKeys("sam");

    driver.findElement(By.name("UserFirstName")).sendKeys("sam");`
```

When I am using

```
driver.findElement(By.id("UserFirstName-m8NQ")).sendKeys("sam");
```

Or
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='UserFirstName-m8NQ']")).sendKeys("sam");

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='UserFirstName-m8NQ']"}
```

In case I use `By.name` I am not getting any error. Here the example:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("UserFirstName")).sendKeys("sam");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below xpath.

```
//input[contains(@id, 'UserFirstName')]
```

When you use dynamic content that appends with id, It changes frequently.
By the way, I could able to find using the xpath,

```
//input[@id='UserFirstName-Q2n8']
```